# How to get the latest file from SFTP in Azure. We have Updateddatetime for each file but how can we add that condition for that

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

How to get the latest file from SFTP in Azure. We have Updateddatetime for each file but how can we add that condition in logic app foreach loop. As we are fetching multiple files from SFTP in azure logic app flow.

Answer (score 1):

While get latest file is not directly supported by the SFTP Connector, it's still easy to do.

1. Use the ListFolder operation to retrieve the metadata for the files in the target folder.
2. Scan the metadata to find the newest file.
3. Use the GetFileContent[ByPath] to retrieve the file.

Comment: Johns-305- in 2 point, how the flow will get know which file is the latest file?

Comment: @sudhanshuPal Sorry, I don't understand.  You have to scan the meta data to find the newest file.  Did you look at the documentation?

Comment: How to scan the metadata to find the newest file. Can i use foreach loop in logic app? Please let me know.

Comment: @sudhanshuPal I have to recommend you try to do this yourself.  If this Answers your question, please mark it as such to benefit future readers.  I you have a specific problem, you can ask a new Question based on that.